# How to add values to confusion matrix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to add values of the confusion matrix I made by my self.

[image: Confusion matrix]

This is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
metrics = np.random.randint(0, 50, (2,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(metrics)
plt.title(f'consusion matrix')
fig.colorbar(cax)
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.show()
```